# If you use the Investment of the Chain Master Eldritch Invocation, does your familiar get a bonus to its saving throw DC from your own magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warlock, familiars, eldritch-invocations

The [Investment of the Chain Master Eldritch Invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) states:

> [...] When you cast find familiar, you infuse the summoned familiar with a measure of your eldritch power, granting the creature the following benefits: [...]
>
> [...] * **If the familiar forces a creature to make a saving throw, it uses your spell save DC.** [...]

My question is, if the warlock has a Rod of the Pact Keeper, or something else which raises their saving throw DC, does the familiar inherit this when it triggers a saving throw?  For example: If I had a DC 14 save with no gear and a DC 15 save with my +1 magic item, would the familiar use a 14 or a 15 for its save DC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### It depends on the item.

[Rod of the Pact Keeper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-the-pact-keeper) only increases the DC *for your warlock spells*:

> While holding this rod, you gain a bonus to spell attack rolls and to the saving throw DCs *of your warlock spells.*

Rod of the Pact Keeper only raises your spell save DC *when you are casting one of your warlock spells*. So Rod of the Pact Keeper would not increase the DC for your familiar, unless you are casting one of your warlock spells through the familiar while using the Rod of the Pact Keeper.

For an item to work with this, it would have to read something like:

> Your spell save DC increases by 1,

*without specifying a use case*, such as the [Robe of the Archmagi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-the-archmagi):

> Your spell save DC and spell attack bonus each increase by 2.

Unlike Rod of the Pact Keeper, Robe of the Archmagi *does not specify when or for what your spell save DC is increased*. It just increases. For everything.

For an example of another feature where Robe of the Archmagi works and Rod of the Pact Keeper does not, let us examine the [Staff of Charming](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-charming):

> While holding this staff, you can use an action to expend 1 of its 10 charges to cast charm person, *command*, or comprehend languages from it using your spell save DC.

In particular, *command* is not a Warlock spell. So when casting *command* from the Staff of Charming, we would not benefit from the Rod of the Pact Keeper's bonus, since *command* is not one of our warlock spells, but we would get the bonus to spell save DC provided by Robe of the Archmagi.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense.  I thought the spell save dc only affected spells.  If there are other uses for it besides this new Tasha's invocation, then your answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117874/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-skavies).

Comment: Command is on the Fiend warlock's expanded spell list, but I do believe now that you are correct.